# How to query feeds data from GitHub v4 API?

Tags: github-api

When I signin github, the github homepage (https://github.com) will show the feed that shows you events from people  you follow and repositories you watch. But how can I fetch the feed data via GitHub v4 API ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see on the Github API V4 pages this isn't possible.
Or it just isn't documented yet.

However it is possible with Github API V3.
https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/feeds/

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it.